# Base64 Pdf in iframe not displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, base64, apex

I'm trying to display a base64 encoded pdf. In FF and Safari the code below displays the pdf in a viewer, however in Chrome the page loads, space is created for the iframe, but the iframe doesn't display.

```
<apex:page controller="SomeController">
    <apex:iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdf}"></apex:iframe>
</apex:page>
```

I have verified that I can indeed view PDF files in Chrome on other webpages and that the Chrome PDF Viewer plugin is enabled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871590/rendering-pdf-in-in-chrome-as-iframe

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working, though our dev team swears that when this was tried initially it didn't work:

```
<apex:page controller="SomeController">
    <object>
        <embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdf}" height="800" width="1200"/>
    </object>
</apex:page>
```

Of course there is the issue that object isn't supported in earlier versions of IE, but at least it works in chrome now.

Comment: Do you really need to wrap the object tag around here? Should it not just be the embed tag?

Comment: @R2D2 In our case, yes we did. We're still not sure why that was necessary, so I can't comment to it being good practice. It would work with it, and not without it. I don't know if this is some strange artifact of APEX, or some other unknown issue. Without the object tag, it did work in FF and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with angular js

```
<embed ng-src="{{NewDocumentData_PDF}}" height="800px;" width="100%;" />
```